The meaning of "it's just the British tend to be more open and direct about it"

We sure do have a class system, and very pernicious it can be too -
but it's not the binary one that foreigners imagine. It's a pretty
complex, convoluted one, in which attitudes, habits, culture, routine
and assumptions are much more important than money or inheritance.
It's a very complex interplay, and people are pretty self-aware about
it. But everywhere has a class system, and for similar reasons -
it's just the British tend to be more open and direct about it. This open-ness and directness can often be taken by visitors to assume
that they've detected something which exists in Britain, but not
elsewhere, when in fact they've detected something which is talked
about in Britain, but less elsewhere.

Is there a class system in England and how is one's position determined within it?
What is the meaning of the part that I have set in bold?
I think that "that" is implied after "just", but I am not sure.

"It is just (that) the British tend to be more open and direct about it."   just = merely.  Does that clear things up, or is there something else that you don't understand about it?  It can be paraphrased as "The British tend to be more open and direct about it -- that's the only difference."

Who wrote this? Where did you get it?

@TimR. Thank you, TimR. Now I have no problem with the sentence structure or the meaning of "just". But I don't know what "more open and direct about it" means. I could use some concrete examples of the open-ness and directness.

Have you consulted any dictionaries for meanings of those words?

To be "open" about something is to be willing to acknowledge it publicly, to be willing to talk about it unabashedly. The word "direct" has similar meanings -- not resorting to euphemism or vague expressions or innuendo but to be candid.   I dion't know if I'd agree with the opinion, but that is what it means.


It's just the British tend to be more open and direct about it.

This is a paragraph about class systems in Britain, and the writer is saying, Yes, we have a class system, but so do many other cultures. So the real contrast is not that Britain has a class system and other cultures don't. It's that Britain talks openly about its class system, while other cultures don't talk about theirs. In that sense Britain is open and direct, while other cultures either hide the fact of class, or perhaps are not aware that there are class issues.
Consider two pubs in a town. Both have a policy that If you drink here, you don't talk about politics or religion. Now imagine that the first pub just assumes that everyone will know this rule, which has been an unwritten law for many years. Imagine also that the second pub has put up this rule as a big sign on the wall, so that even newcomers know what is expected. In this setting we could say the second pub is more open and direct about the expectations that it has.

I consulted five dictionaries to look up "open" and "directly", and I pictured an upper-class person insulting a lower-class person openly and directly. I now know my guess was wrong. Thank you very much, Peter Kirkpatrick.

You're welcome.
